# Problem when list data from Firebase using a foreach

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create the list "localizaciones" with the data created in Firebase Realtime Database of the city of Barcelona. I get the firebase data fine but nothing appears when I want to see the data added to the list using a foreach (ListPlaces()). What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
void Start()
{
    Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
        if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
        {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
        }
        else
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
              "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
        }
    });

}

public void ListDataFB()
{
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
    .GetReference("SITIOS")
    .ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
}


void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.DatabaseError != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
    }

    Debug.Log("Base de datos: " + args.Snapshot.GetRawJsonValue());

    foreach (DataSnapshot sitio in args.Snapshot.Children)
    {
        string ciudadFB = (string)sitio.Child("1_CIUDAD").Value;
        string localizacion = (string)sitio.Child("2_LAT-LON").Value;

        Debug.Log("ciudadFB: " + ciudadFB);
        Debug.Log("localizacion: " + localizacion);

        if (ciudadFB == "BARCELONA")
        {
            List<string> localizaciones = new List<string>();
            localizaciones.Add(localizacion);
            Debug.Log("Añadido a la lista: " + localizacion);
        }

    }
}

public void ListPlaces()
{
    Debug.Log("List Places from List...");

    List<string> localizaciones = new List<string>();

    foreach (string place in localizaciones)
    {
        Debug.Log("PlaceList: " + place.ToString());
    }
}
```

And this is my json in Firebase:

"SITIOS": [
{
"1_CIUDAD": "BARCELONA",
"2_LAT-LON": "41.352881984226855, 2.020995706822936"
},
{
"1_CIUDAD": "BARCELONA",
"2_LAT-LON": "41.35086334867144, 2.0224484975226584"
},
{
"1_CIUDAD": "BARCELONA",
"2_LAT-LON": "41.35265648161525, 2.0223260824563365"
},
{
"1_CIUDAD": "BARCELONA",
"2_LAT-LON": "41.35103815918789, 2.0194211809721705"
},
{
"1_CIUDAD": "MADRID",
"2_LAT-LON": "41.352881984226855, 2.020995706822936"
}
]

Comment: @derHugo Can you take a look, please?

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect from the empty list?

```
List<string> localizaciones = new List<string>();

foreach (string place in localizaciones)
{
    Debug.Log("PlaceList: " + place.ToString());
}
```

You create a new empty list that does not have any elements.

Comment: More of a comment rather then an answer

Comment: Well, you are ok. How can I load the list "localizaciones" to read the elements?

Comment: You should iterate the snapshot you already have here:
`List<string> localizaciones = new List<string>();
foreach (DataSnapshot sitio in args.Snapshot.Children)
{
    string ciudadFB = (string)sitio.Child("1_CIUDAD").Value;
    localizaciones.Add(ciudadFB);
}`